# text overflow in stacked bootstrap nav-tabs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a list of horizontal tabs that can be selected and the tab content has an additional list of tabs (stacked) that shows the content of those tabs next to them.

I created a bootply [here](http://www.bootply.com/lzBlWxTCpI) so you can see what I mean.

Whenever resizing down to xs sizes the text in the tabs will overflow for the stacked tabs and for tabs with a dropdown the dropdown options will be disproportional to the size of the tab

Haven't really found a decent way to get around it. What's a way to fix this? Thought about doing media queries but not sure that's the best route to go.

Comment: How about [this](http://www.bootply.com/OjIV1DW29x#) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my bootply I was giving the nested `nav` stacked tabs (in the tab content) section the class of `nav-stacked` with a class of `col-xs-3`. This was causing problems for whatever reason at these smaller screen sizes.

Removing the `nav-stacked` class and leaving it to be just the regular `nav nav-pills` class worked and correctly shows since each tab is pushed to be stacked anyways due to the small column size. No text overflow.

What about larger screen sizes if you still want them stacked? I just did a hackish solution and set `col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-md-1` so it still forces the tabs to be stacked.

Updated [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/SZFwseboOt)

There's one spot switching from md-sm (I think) could be xs-sm sizes that the tabs display horizontally again. Easily fixed with a media query.